# How are the continue/break statements parsed/represented in ASTs?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I'm attempting to implement for loops into my interpreter, and now am attempting to implement the one token statements `continue` and `break` into the parser.

Considering my lexer,

Lexer

```
"break" -> TOKEN::TBREAK
"continue" -> TOKEN::TCONTINUE
```

I'm considering two ways of implementing them via parsing.
One is to have a two different nodes that will be inserted into the AST called `BreakNode` and `ContinueNode`:

Parser 1

```
BreakGram    -> TOKEN::TBREAK ';' = {new BreakNode();}
ContinueGram -> TOKEN::TCONTINUE ';' = {new ContinueNode();}
```

The other way is to have one shared node for one token statement nodes, inserting the token type as a specifier for what type of statement it would be:

Parser 2

```
OneTokenStatement ->  TOKEN::TBREAK ';' = {new OneTokenStatement(TOKEN::TBREAK);}
                    | TOKEN::TCONTINUE ';' = {new OneTokenStatement(TOKEN::TCONTINUE);}
```

How do other grammars for other languages such as Java/Python handle these two tokens? Are they represented with the different nodes in the AST (like example 1) or with the same node (example 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a judgement call, and I'm sure that both solutions are found in different projects.

The semantics for `break` and `continue` are certainly similar enough that they could be handled by a single function; they both translate into `goto` statements, although obviously to different places. (Also, probably, they exit different scopes.)

Note that they are not single token statements in all languages -- some languages let you specify which loop rather than always using the innermost one -- and there is also  an important difference in some C family languages, in that `break` applies to `switch` blocks but `continue` doesn't.

Personally, I'd probably go with the "different node types" solution, but I don't think it will make much difference.